# Trigger action after user has been on site x minutes everyday using cookies

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

So I need to change the URL of the site if any given user (not logged in) has been browsing the site for more than 3 minutes, and I have to check that daily.

I've tried several ways but none of them is perfect, the logic is easy, everyday check if the user has been using the site for more than 3 minutes, if so, trigger action, but I can't seem to code it correctly.

Attempt 1:

```js
function setReloadXaxis(){
  var date = new Date();
  var minutes = 3;
  date.setTime(date.getTime() + (minutes * 60 * 1000));
  Cookies.set('reloadXaxis', 'tresminutos', { expires: date });
  setInterval(function(){
   if ( Cookies.get('reloadXaxis') !== 'tresminutos' ){
    console.log('reloadXaxis fue false');
    location.href = 'http://digitallpost.com.mx/cultura/cine-series-tv/andrea-legarreta-historia-luis-miguel/';
    Cookies.set('undia', '24hrs', { expires: 1 } );
   }
  }, 20000);
 }

 function checkEveryday(){
  if ( Cookies.get('undia') !== '24hrs' ){
   console.log('undia fue false');
   if ( Cookies.get('reloadXaxis') !== 'tresminutos' ){
    setReloadXaxis();
   }
  }
 }

 checkEveryday();
```

Attempt 2 and 3 weren't successful either as I got stuck in the middle of them, but they used the logic of "for how long has the user been on the site?" instead of reading the cookies.

I've been using cookies to do this but if there is other way (PHP, javascript) I'm ok with it.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think TimeMe.js ([link](https://github.com/jasonzissman/TimeMe.js)) matches your requirement very well. You should check it out.

Comment: @sanfalero thanks but not really, I need something that is site-wise and not page specific as this plugin is.